# Configurable product with simple products

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

I have a configurable product with 3 simple products. On my configurable product, I would like when someone selects an option from dropdown, the content to be changed. I mean some images should be changed and the product description. I tried something with simple products associated to configurable to be visible individually, but the client wants to have the dropdown on a simple products.
Is there any way to achieve this quickly? What solution do you have?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several extension for that, good starting point being: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Answer (score 0):

free version, but is no longer under dev and does not work with v1.9.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

This looks promising:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sdocp-simple-details-on-configurable-products.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and a solution in here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76145/3184

Problem with all the "simple-configurable-products"-like extensions that they result in freaking slow configruable-option selections because every selections is doing an ajax backend call.